# How can I append text field and replace text field by another when I click one of two radio button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

My HTML code like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="pembayaran" id="tunai" value="tunai" onclick="pilihpembayaran()"/>Tunai
<input type="radio" name="pembayaran" id="kredit" value="kredit" onclick="pilihpembayaran()" />Kredit
<input type="text" name="pilihbayar" id="formtunai"readonly value="<?php echo $value->harga?>" style="display:none"/>
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```
function pilihpembayaran(){
    if (document.getElementById('tunai').click) {
        $('#formtunai').show();
    } else if(document.getElementById('kredit').click){
        $('#formtunai').hide();
    }
}
```

But I can't replace element `#formtunai` with another element.

Anyone can solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html

```
 <input type="radio" name="pembayaran" id="tunai" value="tunai" 
 onclick="pilihpembayaran(this)"/>Tunai
 <input type="radio" name="pembayaran" id="kredit" value="kredit" 
 onclick="pilihpembayaran(this)" />Kredit
 <input type="text" name="pilihbayar" id="formtunai"readonly value="<?php echo 
 $value->harga?>" style="display:none"/>
```

Javascript

```
function pilihpembayaran(e){
    var name = $(e).attr('id');
    if(name == "kredit") {
     $('#formtunai').hide();
    } else if(name == "tunai" ) {
     $('#formtunai').show();
    }
}
```

Hope its helps you !

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh , your answer was solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```js
function pilihpembayaran(){
     $("input:radio[id=tunai]").click(function(){
           $('#formtunai').show();
     });
     $("input:radio[id=kredit]").click(function(){
           $('#formtunai').hide();
     });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="pembayaran" id="tunai" value="tunai" onclick="pilihpembayaran()"/>Tunai
<input type="radio" name="pembayaran" id="kredit" value="kredit" onclick="pilihpembayaran()" />Kredit
<input type="text" name="pilihbayar" id="formtunai"readonly value="test" style="display:none"/>
```

Comment: Dont bind click event on every time when user click on radio box

Comment: @Chandra Kumar, But why when I first click radio button tunai, the text field didn't show?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function pilihpembayaran(clickedElemId){
    $("form").hide(); // to hide all forms
    $("#form"+clickedElemId).show(); //to show form based on clicked element id
}
```

```html
 <input type="radio" name="pembayaran" id="tunai" value="tunai" onclick="pilihpembayaran(this.id)"/>Tunai
    <input type="radio" name="pembayaran" id="kredit" value="kredit" onclick="pilihpembayaran(this.id)" />Kredit
<input type="text" name="pilihbayar" id="formtunai"readonly value="<?php echo $value->harga?>" style="display:none"/>
```